# Why Facebook Page Tab apps don't load website in iFrame for others than admin?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I've seen that many others have similar problem, but I haven't found any solution for my case yet. I've tried it with an own and some others' website iFraming apps without success.

My aim is to load an internet radio station player in a tab on my music magazine page by including the station page in an iFrame. I'm not a developer of that site, so I don't send or use any Facebook data there, I just want to display it.

- I've set up my app for Page Tab, that loads the external website into
  the tab.
- The site has SSL, so that's OK.
- I've filled in every required infos in App Details.
- The sandbox mode is turned off.
- While it's a page tab, it can't be sent for submission to the App Center, so review isn't needed.

It does its job well when I'm logged in as the app's admin, but when an another user or a non-registered visitor tries it, the tab is there, but when they try to view it, it displays **"Object moved to here."** The word "here" is a link, but leads nowhere, its URL is wrong. When I examined the URL, it was like: `http://www.thesite.com/?sessionToken=the_token&returnUrl=the_rest_of_the_original_url` So it seems that Facebook put the session token into the URL, but now it can't be loaded by the app. Why does it broke the URL?

When I tried to use another app, that does the same that I want to reach, the result was the same: the site loads in admin account, but **"Object moved to here."** for the others with the wrong URL.

So what else can I check or do? What did I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“So it seems that Facebook put the session token into the URL”_ – no, that has nothing to do with Facebook. It’s the external site that you are trying to embed that issues this redirect, probably as a fallback for the scenario where cookies are not available (and since they would be 3rd-party cookies in this case, it is not that unlikely that the browser wil block them.)

Comment: That's true, they use cookies for store the favorite stations for the visitors. Is it a way to workaround this or I just should give up while it's impossible?

Comment: I tried it out with the direct streaming URL of the radio station, and it works with that, so it's really because of the cookies of the station info site. But I have no idea if I can do anything for that to work.

Comment: Ask them, whether they would be willing to provide you with a possibility to embed their content as part of a Facebook app. If they are not, perhaps then they wouldn’t even _want_ you to do that in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I will surely ask them, cause as I was diggin in their forum, I found other users also complained that they can't embed their player into Facebook apps. It was working before Facebook's last big update, but now it doesn't. So it seems that it's not exactly because of Facebook, but also the way this radio server handle their site. I hope they will listen to us. Thanks for your idea.